# YouTube Data API v3: List all videos for a channel published in the last 24 hours, ignoring "placeholders"

Tags: youtube-data-api

I've had some code in production for 6 months or so that runs every 24 hours and pulls all videos from certain YouTube channels that were published in the last 24 hours (i.e. since it last checked).  It's been working well.

However, a couple of the YouTube channels this code monitors publish some kind of "placeholder" or "teaser" a day or two ahead of publishing the actual video, which means that my code "sees" the video twice:

1. when the placeholder is published;
2. when the actual video is published.

I'm not interested in #1, since there's no video actually available yet, just a teaser that it's "coming soon".  I'm only interested in knowing about the video once it's actually been published.  Is there a way to filter out these placeholders from my search, so that my code only "sees" the video when it is actually published?  A search parameter would be ideal, but if this can only be done by filtering of the result in my own code (e.g. by returned metadata), that would work too.

For reference, here's the URL my code hits:

`https://youtube.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&channelId=[CHANNEL_ID]&order=date&publishedAfter=[NOW_MINUS_24_HOURS]&key=[MY_API_KEY]`

[Here's an example of a video where this happened](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UI210v9-yoY), albeit I don't think there's any way to know that a placeholder had been published a day or two prior to the video going up.

Comment: Please provide a video ID that subsumes to your case #1.

Comment: Also please mention you programming language/environment.

Comment: @stvar the video ids don't change between step 1 and step 2, which is part of the problem. So the example I provided in the top post is an example video id (though of course you can't see the placeholder, since it was replaced by the full video a day or two later).

Programming language/environment is irrelevant since I can use raw URL requests to reproduce it (via the Google API explorer, curl, httpie, etc.).

Comment: You've got me wrong: *I wasn't expecting the video IDs to change at all.* But am expecting that a video of the kind described by your case 1 *to have its metadata significantly different* than one of the kind described by case 2.

Comment: On the other hand, in the context of YouTube Data API, programming languages/environments *are indeed very much relevant*, only if thinking at the plethora of Google API client libraries: different languages/environments imply quite *significant differences* between actual code invoking the API. Of course, one could well have a language-agnostic description of API endpoints calls (as, e.g., the official docs have), but, nota bene, that would inherently be quite remote from *concrete (ready to use) solutions*.

Comment: Here is the answer to your question: [Finding premieres through Youtube API](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63875379/8327971). You need ignore the premieres from a `Search.list` query: the answer quoted provides you the *negated filtering condition* for to achieve precisely that (just skip to the *UPDATE* section).

Comment: I gave you a solution by filtering what was returned, based on the JSON.  Is this not working for you?

Comment: Mark H, I think you might be replying to @stvar, who is someone else.

Comment: @stvar programming language/environment is _not_ relevant, as I can reproduce this problem using raw URL requests (via the Google API explorer, curl, httpie, etc.), and am only interested in answers that solve it purely using those same mechanisms (or by describing any post-request filtering logic using non-language/environment specific terms, as Mark H did below).

Comment: @Peter: Mark H's solution below *is incomplete* since *it does not discriminate* between **live broadcasts** and **premieres** ("placeholders" as per your ad-hoc non-YouTube term). The two kinds of videos are very much different categories. That's why I indicated you an already given answer on this forum that filters out exactly the *premieres*, leaving in the *live broadcasts*. Again, the implementation language **is always relevant** when things are about concrete solutions (this being derived from a plethora of reasons that I suppose you know well).

Comment: @stvar none of the channels I'm interrogating publish live broadcasts, nor are they likely to at any point in the future. If they were, I would have provided that information in my original post.  And at the risk of repeating myself for a third time, I can reproduce this problem using raw URL requests (via the Google API explorer, curl, httpie, etc.), and am only interested in answers that solve it purely using those same mechanisms (or by describing any post-request filtering logic using non-language/environment specific terms). I can only explain this to you; I can't understand it for you.

Comment: @Peter: *I would have*, but *actually did not* is not a valid form of communication; redundancy is always a premise for exchange of information of the good quality kind. Unfortunately, you provided no relevant answer to any of my very much legitimate questions (derived upon digesting your description -- which is quite *incomplete* as per your very own acknowledgement). That's saddening, since ([quote](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)): ***Stack Overflow** is a question and answer site for professional and enthusiast programmers.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you [can't change a video](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/55770) to make it longer (only shorter) once it's been uploaded, and uploading a new video results in a new URL, I assume they're using the "Premiere" option when uploading.

Video search results for YouTube's Premiere option will have the following property returned in the json before actually airing:

`"liveBroadcastContent": "upcoming",`

This will change to the following after being aired:

`"liveBroadcastContent": "none",`

I don't actually see a way to apply the filter as a query parameter.  There's `&eventType=none&type=video`, as listed on the [search API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list) page, but that only works for LIVE/broadcast events.  This is a bit of an inconsistency/incompleteness in the API, IMHO.

Comment: Thanks Mark H - this seems to be it.  And yes, it's a great shame that this filtering has to be done client side.  Very sloppy API design / implementation.

Comment: The pre-recorded premiere is "live-broadcast" at its premiere date (i.e. you can't fast forward, only rewind) and there's "live chat," but it's not a "live" program.  It seems to me that they made the pre-recorded premiere possible within the framework of an API that didn't perfectly accommodate one.

Comment: Ah the square pegs that our industry loves jamming into round holes...  