# YouTube API: differentiating between Premiered and Livestream

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api, youtube-livestreaming-api

I am using YouTube data API and trying to differentiate prior livestreams vs premiered content. The liveStreamingDetails in the video list is populated for both livestreams and premiered content. Is there a way I can differentiate between the two?

Below is my python code for getting live stream start time. If its not populated, then I know that video is not live stream. But the problem is that this value is getting populated for premiered content as well.

```
vid_request = youtube.videos().list(part = 'contentDetails, statistics, snippet, liveStreamingDetails, status',id = ','.join(vid_ids))
vid_response =  vid_request.execute()  
        
for videoitem in vid_response['items']:
    try:
         livestreamStartTime = videoitem['liveStreamingDetails']['actualStartTime']
    except:
        livestreamStartTime = ''
```

Any pointers on what could work would really help?

Comment: This is the answer to your question: [Finding premieres through Youtube API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59445665/finding-premieres-through-youtube-api).

Comment: Thanks for your inputs. But I am looking to differentiate between prior uploaded videos and not upcoming ones. I can do it on website looking at text after view count. Is there some way I could do the same through API. Below is an example of text for view count under a (i)Livestream video and (ii)Premiere videos:

(i) 86,164 views Streamed live on Jul 16, 2021 
(ii) 357,103 views Premiered Jul 11, 2021 

.One option is if I can get this text or else some identifier in API which differentiates this. Both of these are not upcoming but prior uploaded content which I want to analyze.

Comment: Unfortunately, the metadata provided by the API (specifically by the [`Videos.list`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list) endpoint) *does not allow* one to discriminate whether *an already uploaded video was a premiere or not*.

Comment: Thanks. Is there any simple way to get the text next to view count on YouTube website. I can use that for differentiation. Also, is there some computationally inexpensive workaround possible using search API. I get about 4000+ videos in my data of which about 200+ would be either livestream or premiered. Any way possible in search API or any other route to work on just these 200.

Comment: I have added this as feature request here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/194118310